# Нужно найти сумму первых трех цифр дробной части вещественного числа

Tags: c++, олимпиада

> Вводится одно вещественное число, которое не превосходит по модулю
>   105105, задано с точностью до четырёх знаков после запятой. Формат
>   выходных данных
>
> Выведите целое число — искомую сумму.
>
> Примеры
>
> входные данные
>   123.4567
>
> выходные данные 15
>
> входные данные
>   42.4242
>
> выходные данные 10

P.S Решение не должно включать в себя ни строки , ни массивы , ни циклы ни условные операторы.
Можно пользоваться заголовочными файлами `<iomanip>` и `<cmath>`

Comment: с чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: Не знаю как найти числа после запятой

Comment: умножив исходное число на 1000 а затем взяв от результата остаток от деления на 1000, получается число из трех цифр дробной части исходного числа

Comment: @Matviei Skufin  Как вы для этого числа  123.4567  получили выходные данные 15?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, 4+5+6 = 15, и в заголовке: _найти сумму первых трех цифр дробной части вещественного числа_

Comment: ( (int)(x*10) + (int)(x*100)%10 + (int)(x*1000)%10)

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin Вы качестве примера привели числа с 4 дробными цифрами, то  подумал, что нужно их всех суммировать.

Comment: @pavel Ваш пример у меня не работает
 `#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    float a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << (int)(a * 10) + (int)(a * 100) % 10 + (int)(a * 1000) % 10 << endl;
    return 0;

}`

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin обновите ваш вопрос и укажите что именно "у меня не работает" означает: какой конкретно вывод ожидали, что вместо этого происходит—опишите детально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, причем здесь условие

> Вводится одно вещественное число, которое не превосходит по модулю
>   105105

то есть ограничение на абсолютную величину, так как оно никакой роли не играет.

Без проверки этого условия (которое вы сами можете вставить в программу)  программа может, к примеру, выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const int Base = 10;
        const int N = 3;

        std::cout << "Enter a float number with "
                     "a fraction of at least " << N + 1 << " digits (0 - exit ): ";

        double d;

        if (!(std::cin >> d) || d == 0) break;

        double int_part;
        double fraction;

        fraction = std::modf(std::fabs( d ), &int_part);

        int sum = int(fraction * Base) % Base +
            int(fraction * Base * Base) % Base +
            int(fraction * Base * Base * Base) % Base;

        std::cout << "The sum of " << N << " digits of the fraction is "
            << sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Действительно, если последовательно ввести значения 123.4567 и 42.4242, то вывод на консоль будет выглядеть как предполагается в вашем задании

```
Enter a float number with a fraction of at least 4 digits (0 - exit ): 123.4567
The sum of 3 digits of the fraction is 15
Enter a float number with a fraction of at least 4 digits (0 - exit ): 42.4242
The sum of 3 digits of the fraction is 10
Enter a float number with a fraction of at least 4 digits (0 - exit ): 0
```

Вместо функции `modf` из `<cmath>` можно было бы просто записать

```
double fraction = std::fabs( d ) - int( std::fabs( d ) );
```

чтобы убрать целую часть числа.

Comment: Это хорошая идея, но не обязательно modf() использовать, учитывая входной диапазон, [пример](http://ideone.com/QqX32V)

Comment: @jfs У меня в конце ответа написано, как можно вызов функции заменить.:)

Comment: И вычитать также не обязательно. Нажмите на ссылку в моём комментарии.

Comment: @jfs С вычитанием никакого ограничения на размер введенного числа не требуется.

Comment: 1- Ограничение в вопросе есть. 2- вариант с вычитанием сломается, если нет ограничения.

Comment: @jfs Почему ломается, если нет ограничений на абсолютную величину? Вы имеете в виду, что целая часть не поместится в целочисленном типе? Но тогда в качестве ограничения надо было брать либо INT_MAX  или даже LLONG_MAX.

Comment: фраза "никакого ограничения" означает "никакого ограничения"

Comment: Позволю себе заметить, что при обобщенном (`N`) числе цифр у вас все же считается сумма именно для `N=3` цифр...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Тут такое дело. 
`#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float d,fraction;
    cin >> d;
    fraction = fabs(d) - (int)fabs( d );
    int sum;
    sum = (int)(fraction * 10) % 10 + (int)(fraction * 100) % 10 + (int)(fraction * 1000) % 10;
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}`

Вот этот код не работает в 1 тесте , когда вводится число 1.1110.

Тест #12

Input 1.1110
Output 2
Correct 3

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin Я думаю, условие ввода именно 4 цифр установлено специально. Последняя цифра не должна быть 0. Когда имеешь дело с числами с плавающей запятой, то они не имеют точного представления. Поэтому надо вводить четыре десятичные цифры.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Что мне стоит сделать , что бы исправить проблему?

Comment: @MatvieiSkufin По условиям задачи это не является проблемой, так как нужно ввести четыре дробные цифры, и, я думаю, что предполагается, что последняя цифра не будет равна 0, так как иначе выглядит, как будто бы ввели только три цифры. Но вы можете попробовать округлить до третьей дробной цифры.

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/Ti9lse

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char a='0', b='0', c='0';

    scanf("%*d.%c%c%c", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d\n", a+b+c-'0'*3);

    return 0;
}
```