# Есть ли 0 среди первых трёх цифр после запятой?

Tags: c++

Задано положительное число с плавающей точкой. Определить есть ли среди первых трех цифр дробной части цифра 0.

Comment: Домашние задания делают не тут...

Comment: OK, пишите код, разрешаем :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно найти сумму первых трех цифр дробной части вещественного числа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590287/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Домашние задания предназначены для развития Ваших знаний. Чтобы Вам помогли, Вам необходимо показать, как Вы сами пробовали решить задачу и/или что у Вас не получается/не понимаете.

Comment: я хочу ответить на этот вопрос ))

Comment: есть два варианта, первый это колхозно взять перевести число в строку и банально проверить на наличие нулевого символа, второй алгоритм - берём дробную часть домножаем на 10 и проверяем целую часть (1 цифру, так как умножаем на 10) на ноль 3 раза - реализуйте хотя бы первым способом, чтобы была какая то вам польза

Comment: Я попытался бы определить наличие нуля визуально. Как он выглядит, я знаю (помню)...вот и поискал бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм.. Лишнего многовато... Но работать должно бы, наверное.
К тому же, оно прямоугольное :)

```js
res = 'bool check(double x)\n{ x%=1; return //';

for (var a=0; a<10; ++a)
  for (var b=0; b<10; ++b)
    for (var c=0; c<10; ++c)
      if (!a || !b || !c)
        res += ' ||\nx>=.'+a+b+c + ' && x<.'+(a+!a)+!!a*(b+!b)+!!a*!!b*(c+!c);

res += ' ;}';

document.body.textContent = res;
```

```css
body { 
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```